# Object attribute not recognized by object's functions [Python]

Tags: python

I'm running into a strange error.

```
import socket
from string_message_converter import StringMessageConverter as SMC
from sbe_message_converter import SBEMessageConverter
from abstract_publisher import AbstractFoo
import config
class Foo(AbstractFoo):

    def __init__(self, p_id):
        self.sock = 1
        self.p_id = p_id

    def connect(self):
        ttl = 2
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)
```

I have a main method which relies on this class. When I run connect(), I get a NameError 'global name 'sock' is not defined'. But sock is not global; it is an attribute I define in __init__. The weird thing is that the same error does not occur for p_id. For example:

MulticastPublisher.py:

```
class Foo(AbstractFoo):

        def __init__(self, p_id):
            self.sock = 1
            self.p_id = p_id

        def connect(self):
            ttl = 2
            self.p_id = 2
            print self.p_id
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)
```

will print '2' for p_id (will still break on the self.sock in connect as before too). Moreover, I ran the same code on a different machine and it runs fine. Why isn't self.sock being recognized?

Edit: the main method is just two lines.

testmain_pub.py

```
def main():

    f = Foo()
    f.start_process() #references connect method
```

the stack trace is just referencing the connect method:

```
  File "testmain_pub.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "testmain_pub.py", line 9, in main
    m.publish_start("start message")
  File "/home/observe_and_report/multicast_publisher.py", line 48, in publish_start
    self.publish("start", message)
  File "/home/observe_and_report/multicast_publisher.py", line 35, in publish
    self.connect()
  File "/home/observe_and_report/multicast_publisher.py", line 30, in connect
    self.sock = socket.socket(sock.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Comment: Can you put the full code example including the main?

Comment: The full stack trace would also be quite useful.

Comment: I believe the error is **global name 'socket' is not defined**, not **sock**. You need to add a line saying `import socket` to the beginning of the script.

Comment: *Actual* full stack trace, copied and pasted from actual interpreter output, please.

Comment: @HaiVu I do have the imports, I just omitted them from my question

Comment: By any chance, are you now running `main` from a python shell?

Comment: What is `start_process`, exactly?

Comment: You have a typo in the code: `sock.AF_INET`.

Comment: @bereal not from python shell. simply from command line. In my other machine I run it through a IDE

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't copy the exact same code. You are calling the `start_process` method which doesn't exists in the example. The traceback says `sock.AF_INET` and the example says `socket.AF_INET`, and it's also incomplete, without the actual message error.

Comment: @chepner was right, I must have glazed over the typo in the stack trace. I fixed it and it running as it should be. Also I apologize for not posting the full code. The method calls reference methods I've written in several different files and classes and for the sake of convenience I omitted them. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: In your main, `f = Foo()` will not work. You are not giving us the real code.

Comment: I believe @PabloDíazOgni is correct. The stack trace said `sock.AF_INET` and that is your problem in your real code.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but your error is elsewhere, not in the code that you show to us. I just take what you gave and strip down to bare minimum and everything works.

```
import socket

class AbstractFoo:
    pass

class Foo(AbstractFoo):
    def __init__(self, p_id):
        self.sock = 1
        self.p_id = p_id

    def connect(self):
        ttl = 2
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        print 'self.sock =', self.sock
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)

def main():
    f = Foo(123)
    f.connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
self.sock = <socket._socketobject object at 0x10f4b91a0>
```

## Update

You should take a hint from @PabloDíazOgni: the problem is here: `sock.AF_INET`, which is in the code that you are not showing to us.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was actually with a typo in socket.AF_INET. In the code that was running in putty (where it was having problems) I had a typo where instead of socket.AF_INET I wrote sock.AF_INET. I was having trouble copying from putty for some reason so I copied from my other machine where it was working fine thinking they were the same code.